# plot the bars from starttime not from zero

Tags: python

for example i have the values

```
starTime1 = 1.5
starTime2 = 3
starTime3 = 2.3
```

and i have three bars horizantal, for example with name:
bar1
bar2
bar3

i have "x" scale = 24 hours(range0,24)

So how to plot the bars from values "startTime", not from zero.

There is my code. variable "rankings" it's the endtime of bar.

```
import csv
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

numCp = 10
cpNames = [data[4][6], data[5][6], data[6][6], data[7][6],
         data[8][6], data[9][6], data[10][6], data[11][6],
         data[12][6], data[13][6]]
testMeta = ['UOL/sec' , 'UOL/sec', 'UOL/sec', 'UOL/sec', 'UOL/sec', 'UOL/sec',     'UOL/sec', 'UOL/sec', 'UOL/sec', 'UOL/sec' ]
scores = [data[4][4], data[5][4], data[6][4], data[7][4], data[8][4],
      data[9][4], data[10][4], data[11][4], data[12][4], data[13][4]]
rankings = intAllCpMin



fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 7)) #height and width of chart
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.115, right=0.88)
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Eldorado K-8 Fitness Chart')
pos = np.arange(numCp)+0.5   # Center bars on the Y-axis ticks
rects = ax1.barh(pos, rankings, align='center', height=0.5, color='m')

ax1.axis([0, 100, 0, 10]) # to display all CP bars correctly change last number on     numbers of CP
pylab.yticks(pos, cpNames)
ax1.set_title('Non Functional Test Results')
plt.text(50, -0.5, 'Hours',
     horizontalalignment='center', size='small')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot([totalRunTime, totalRunTime], [0, 5], 'white', alpha=0.1) #width of X
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(totalRunTime))
xticks = pylab.setp(ax2, xticklabels=[lowestStartTime," "," "," "," "," ",     higherStartTime])
ax2.xaxis.grid(True, linestyle='--', which='major', color='grey',
alpha=0.25)

def withnew(i, scr):
    if testMeta[i] != '':
        return '%s\n' % scr
    else:
        return scr

scoreLabels = [withnew(i, scr) for i, scr in enumerate(scores)]
scoreLabels = [i+j for i, j in zip(scoreLabels, testMeta)]
ax2.set_yticks(pos)
ax2.set_yticklabels(scoreLabels)
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())


ax2.set_ylabel('Test Scores')

suffixes = sorted([str(data[4][14][5:12]), data[5][14][5:12], data[6][14][5:12], data[7][14][5:12], data[8][14][5:12],
               data[9][14][5:12],data[10][14][5:12], data[11][14][5:12], data[12][14]    [5:12], data[13][14][5:12]])


    width = int(rect.get_width())

    rankStr = ""
    if (width < 2):        # The bars aren't wide enough to print the ranking inside
        xloc = width+0.1  # Shift the text to the right side of the right edge
        clr = 'black'      # Black against white background
        align = 'left'
        rankStr += suffixes[1] + " Total Run Time"
    else:
        xloc = 0.50*width  # Shift the text to the left side of the right edge
        clr = 'white'      # White on magenta
        align = 'center'
        rankStr += suffixes[1] + " Total Run Time"

        yloc = rect.get_y()+rect.get_height()/2.0
        ax1.text(xloc, yloc,  suffixes[1], horizontalalignment=align,
        verticalalignment='center', color=clr, weight='bold')


plt.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't run. `data` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `left` keyword to `barh` (or the `bottom` keyword for vertical bars) to change the starting position of a bar.  You'll have to subtract the same amount from the bar length though.

Example:

```
pylab.barh( [1,2,3], [10,20,30], left=20 )
```